# Tkinter simple "enter password" dialog

Tags: python, tkinter, input

I know it's possible to define a custom "Enter password" dialog, see [Implementing a Password Dialog with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326898/implementing-a-password-dialog-with-tkinter).

But is it possible to re-use `tkinter.simpledialog.askstring`, as explained in this answer: [Python: How to get an entry box within a message box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779540/python-how-to-get-an-entry-box-within-a-message-box/45087774#45087774)

and just replace the typed text by `****` automatically on each keypress?

Or better, does `tkinter.simpledialog` already implement a password input dilaog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`askstring()` function can use the attribute `show` if you set it to `show="*"` should do exactly what you need it to do. Example below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
password = askstring('Password', 'Enter password:', show="*")
showinfo('Show password', 'password input: {}'.format(password))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! and the `withdraw` [was useful as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406145/how-do-i-get-rid-of-python-tkinter-root-window), thanks for this!